# How to add pallet contract for polkadot-v1.0.0?

Tags: pallet, pallet-contracts

How to add pallet contract for polkadot-v1.0.0? Do I only need to change the `node/runtime` folder or the `runtime` folder at root or both?

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: I used the substrated node template, then add some pallets to switch from PoA to PoS. I am then trying to follow this repo: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs to add contract pallet..but keep getting errors.

Answer (score 1):

My advice, start with a fully functioning Substrate node that is at `1.0.0`.

Once you have a fully functioning `1.0.0` node then add pallet contracts.

You can use the kitchensink node as a reference:

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/e2b21d00c7856961ab3b692b2e2798747af1e819/substrate/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1307-L1350

If you run into issues there then open a Stack Exchange question with the specific problem and how to replicate it so the community can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) for reference. It is a substrate-contracts-node template which is being updated regularly with the polkadot-versions.